# dont count br and nbsp in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string consist of "br" an "nbsp;" tags , what i need is that i need to have limit the character to 100, which means only 100 characters should show, since each "br" takes 4 characters instead of 100 i am getting 108, to getting below output i can do it in  a single line

```
data.substr(0,100)
```

output =>

> it to make a type specimen book. 
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap

but it includes br tag i dont want to remove br and nbsp; but don't count that

expected output =>

> it to make a type specimen book. 
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into ele

i have done some snippet, but it gives the count of 108

```js
var data = `it to make a type specimen book. <br><br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br><br>remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages<br><br>, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including&nbsp; versions of Lorem Ipsum.`
// removes nbsp
var docDesc = data.replace(/[&]nbsp[;]/gi," "); 
// removes br
var stringData = docDesc.replace(/[<]br[^>]*[>]/gi,""); 
var subData =  stringData.substr(0,100)
function test(subData) {
    
 var n = subData.split(" ");
    
 return n.slice(Math.max(n.length - 5, 1))


}
var lastData = test(subData);
var lastString = lastData.join(" ")
var finalData = data.substring(0,data.indexOf(lastString)) + lastString

console.log(finalData)
console.log(finalData.length)
```

Comment: Why can't you have just a simpler `<br.*>` as your regexp? Also, what if you have escaping characters, like `\<br\>`? Those `<` and `>` will not be considered as escaped and will match your regex.

Comment: @ChatterOne the string that i am getting is from a ajax response , so i can't edit that one.

Comment: @ChatterOne i need to show the data in the same alignment but i need to limit the character with 100 by not counting br and nbsp

Comment: Yes, I understood your requirement and I asked why you can't use a different regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form you can write a function that acts like substring but excludes some 'words', like so:

```
function substringWithExcludes(str, excludes, length) {
    let idx = 0;
    let len = 0;

    while(idx < str.length && len < length){
        let match = false;

        for(let exclude of excludes) {
            if(str.startsWith(exclude, idx)) {
                idx += exclude.length;
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!match) {
            len++;
            idx++;
        }
    }

    return str.substring(0, idx);
}
```

Which is called like:

```
const data = `it to make a type specimen book. <br>\r\n<br>\r\nIt has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br>\r\n<br>\r\nremaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages<br>\r\n<br>\r\n, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including&nbsp; versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;

const result = substringWithExcludes(data, ["\r", "\n", "&nbsp;", "<br>"], 100);
```

`len` keeps track of the length of the string without the `<br>` and all that, while `idx` includes these matches. What we need to do for each exclude is, is to see if it matches in the first place, and if it does add the length to `idx`. If it doesn't match its a valid character that needs to be included (increment both `len` and `idx`).

Might be slow for large `length` and many `excludes`, but it gets the job done. You can add specific cases for case-insensitivity, and `<br />` matching if necessary. `startsWith` can be swapped with a regex match when required.

Answer (score 0):

**@DILEEP**, please have a look at the below code.

> And also comment if you face any problem in understanding the code, I will try my best to answer you.

```js
/*
 Function takes a string (data)
 Returns string with first 100 characters from index 0 to 100 (default)
 Returns string based on explicity passed values of start and end
*/
function get100charsNoCountBrsAndSpaces(data, start=0, end=100) {
 var arr = stringToArrWithNoBrsAndSpaces(data)
 let arrSpaces = arr.map((item) => {
  return item.join(' ')
 })

 let strBrsSpaces = arrSpaces.join(' '); // "sdd fhhf fhhhf fhhf"
 var finalStr;
 var spacesCount = 0;

    // 
 do {
  finalStr = strBrsSpaces.slice(start, end + spacesCount)
  
  spacesCount = finalStr.match(/\s/gi).length
 } 
 while(finalStr.slice(start, end + spacesCount).split(' ').join('').length < 100);
 
    return finalStr.slice(start, end + spacesCount)
}

/*
 Function that removes <br> and spaces from string (data) 
 and returns a 2d array (it helps us in recontruction of original string)
*/
function stringToArrWithNoBrsAndSpaces(data)  {
 var arrNoBrs = data.split('<br>')
 // console.log(JSON.stringify(arrNoBrs, null, 4))

 let arrNoBrsSpaces = arrNoBrs.map((item) => {
  let a = []; //let: local scope of a
  a = item.split(' ')
  return a;
 })

 // console.log(JSON.stringify(arrNoBrsSpaces, null, 4))
 return arrNoBrsSpaces
}

/*
 Function which reconstructs the string from the 2 array
 Adds spaces and <br> at proper places
*/
function arrWithNoBrsAndSpacesToString(array)  {
 let arrSpaces = array.map((item) => {
  return item.join(' ')
 })
 console.log(arrSpaces)
 // console.log(arrSpaces)
 let strBrsSpaces = arrSpaces.join('<br>')
 return strBrsSpaces
}

// ********* Testing: stringToArrsWithNoBrsAndSpaces()
var inputStr = `it to make a type specimen book. <br><br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br><br>remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages<br><br>, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including&nbsp; versions of Lorem Ipsum.`
var arr = stringToArrWithNoBrsAndSpaces(inputStr)
console.log(arr)

console.log('\n')

// ********* Testing: arrWithNoBrsAndSpacesToString()
var str = arrWithNoBrsAndSpacesToString(arr)
console.log(str)

// ********* Testing: get100charsNoCountBrsAndSpaces(inputStr)
var finalData = get100charsNoCountBrsAndSpaces(inputStr)
console.log('finalData:', finalData)
console.log('Length:', finalData.length) // 122 (100 char + 22 spaces), see below line
console.log('Number of spaces:', finalData.match(/\s/ig).length)
console.log('Number of chars :', finalData.split(' ').join('').length) // 100

/* ...** Output: stringToArrsWithNoBrsAndSpaces(inputStr) **...

[
    [
        "it",
        "to",
        "make",
        "a",
        "type",
        "specimen",
        "book.",
        ""
    ],
    [
        ""
    ],
    [
        "It",
        "has",
        "survived",
        "not",
        "only",
        "five",
        "centuries,",
        "but",
        "also",
        "the",
        "leap",
        "into",
        "electronic",
        "typesetting,",
        ""
    ],
    [
        ""
    ],
    [
        "remaining",
        "essentially",
        "unchanged.",
        "It",
        "was",
        "popularised",
        "in",
        "the",
        "1960s",
        "with",
        "the",
        "release",
        "of",
        "Letraset",
        "sheets",
        "containing",
        "Lorem",
        "Ipsum",
        "passages"
    ],
    [
        ""
    ],
    [
        ",",
        "and",
        "more",
        "recently",
        "with",
        "desktop",
        "publishing",
        "software",
        "like",
        "Aldus",
        "PageMaker",
        "including&nbsp;",
        "versions",
        "of",
        "Lorem",
        "Ipsum."
    ]
]
*/


/* ...** Output: arrWithNoBrsAndSpacesToString(arr) **...

it to make a type specimen book. <br><br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br><br>remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages<br><br>, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including&nbsp; versions of Lorem Ipsum.

*/


/* ...** Output: get100charsNoCountBrsAndSpaces(inputStr) **...

it to make a type specimen book. <br><br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <br><br>remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages<br><br>, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including&nbsp; versions of Lorem Ipsum.
finalData: it to make a type specimen book.   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
Length: 122
Number of spaces: 22
Number of chars : 100

*/
```

Thanks.